# Can you make a single filter with multiple fields in Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a grid populated with items that contain multiple different fields to them, and I've created a search bar that I intend to use to search the grid for items with fields that match the searched term. It's just going to apply a filter to the grid with the given term. I've got it working that I can type something in and search by title, but I want to expand upon this and be able to search for any of the fields in the grid.

For example, an object `foo` may have the fields `Title`, `Description`, `ID`, and `Display Name`. I can create a filter like this to search the grid explicitly for matches within the `Title` field:

`let newFilter = { field: "Title", operator: "contains", value: term };`

where `term` is the variable representing the user input. And this is where I'm a little confused as to what to do next: can I somehow make one filter that, rather than using the hardcoded "Title" as its field, searches any of the `foo` fields for the matching term? Or would I have to create 4 different filters, one for each field, and then put an 'or' on them telling the grid to show me results with the term from any of the fields? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality with only one filter. Take one extra field which contains all the field values.

**For example:**

```
Current sample record: {"Title":"MR", "Description":"Hello", "ID":"1234", "DisplayName":"TestDisplay"}

After adding one new field with all the values: {"Title":"MR", "Description":"Hello", "ID":"1234", "DisplayName":"TestDisplay", "AllTheValues":"MR Hello 1234 TestDisplay"}
```

Map this new field in the filter:

```
let newFilter = { field: "AllTheValues", operator: "contains", value: term };
```

For displaying purpose, you can use [Kendo Grid column template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template) to display whatever the value you want in the grid column.

Ex: `{ field: "AllTheValues", template: "<strong>#: Title# </strong>" }`